# Is there any library from which we can we get marquee effect in recyclerview(e.g hotstar vip page scrolling images)?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll, marquee

> Blockquote

i am trying to achieve auto scrolling infinite recyclerview like hotstar have it in hotstar VIP subscription page.

i have tried given code.

For auto scrolling recycler:-

binding.rvPartyOfWeek.addOnScrollListener(CustomScrollListener())

```
private val SCROLLING_RUNNABLE = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        val duration = 10
        val pixelsToMove = 22

        if (!isPartyOfWeekScrolling) {
            binding.rvPartyOfWeek.smoothScrollBy(pixelsToMove, 0)
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, duration.toLong())
    }
}
```

For infinite scroll:-

```
binding.rvPartyOfWeek.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView2: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView2, dx, dy)
                val totalItemCount = layoutManagerparty.itemCount
                val lastVisibleItem = layoutManagerparty.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
                if (totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + 3)) {
                    if (totalItemCount > 22) {
                        for (i in 0..10) {
                            listParty.removeAt(0)
                        }
                    }
                    listParty.addAll(listPartySingle)
                    adapterpartyofweek.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    Log.i("Helllo listParty", listParty.size.toString())
                }
            }
        })
```

It is not scrolling smoothly in some device and crashing in some old devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as follows:

1. Creating auto scroll for RecyclerView

`

```
private fun autoScroll() {
        scrollCount = 0;
        var speedScroll: Long = 1200;
        val runnable = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                if (layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() >= imageArrayList.size / 2) {
                    adapter.load()
                }
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(scrollCount++)
                Log.e(TAG, "run: $scrollCount")
                handler.postDelayed(this, speedScroll)
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, speedScroll)
    }
```

`

2. Create Smooth scroll automatically

`

```
layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity) {
            override fun smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State?, position: Int) {
                val smoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(this@MainActivity) {
                    override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics?): Float {
                        return 5.0f;
                    }
                }
                smoothScroller.targetPosition = position
                startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
            }
        }
```

`

For source Code, check out the GitHub project link
https://github.com/Mahesh2318/AutoScrollRecyclerView

Comment: Thanks for answer but for only one or two item this is not working

Comment: Have you checked that https://github.com/Mahesh2318/AutoScrollRecyclerView?
or if possible, share your code with me so I can check it.